# error occurs when installing pip

Tags: python, installation, pip

I don't know what to do next to fix? All the things are in red!
this is what shows when I conducted the final step using : python get-pip.py
I just follow the instructions getting from

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
   .....(too long)
   conn = self.get_connection(request.url, proxies)
  File "/tmp/tmpGK7Hjj/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 290, in get_connection
    proxy_manager = self.proxy_manager_for(proxy)
  File "/tmp/tmpGK7Hjj/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 184, in proxy_manager_for
    **proxy_kwargs
  File "/tmp/tmpGK7Hjj/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/contrib/socks.py", line 154, in __init__
    "Unable to determine SOCKS version from %s" % proxy_url
ValueError: Unable to determine SOCKS version from socks://10.77.8.70:8080/
```

This is what shows when enter

```
 whereis python?
 python: /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python3.5m /usr/bin/python /usr/bin  /python2.7-config /usr/bin/python3.5 /usr/lib/python2.7 /usr/lib/python3.5 /etc/python2.7 /etc/python /etc/python3.5 /usr/local/lib/python2.7 /usr/local/lib/python3.5 /usr/include/python2.7 /usr/share/python /usr/share/man/man1/python.1.gz


 whereis pip?
 pip: /usr/local/bin/pip3.5 /usr/local/bin/pip /usr/local/bin/pip2.7
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: If your problem is solved, please select the answer below

Answer (score 0):

To intsall pip for Python2 use the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

For Python3 use

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```